# TcpListener intermittently not working

Tags: c#, http, proxy, tcplistener

Attempting to write a basic proxy I have implemented code along the following lines as a start.

```
private Thread _proxyThread;

public void Start() 
{
    this._proxyThread = new Thread(StartListener);
    this._proxyThread.Start();
}

protected void StartListener(object data)
{
    this._listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
    this._listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = this._listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        while (client.Connected)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while (stream.DataAvailable && stream.CanRead)
            {   
                int i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                request.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i));                        
            }

            if (stream.CanWrite)
            {
                byte[] response = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + Environment.NewLine + "Content-length: 4\r\n\r\n" + "Test");
                stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I then set my LAN proxy like this

[image: Proxy]

My current goal (as you can hopefully deduce from my code) is to return just a text value with no headers or anything.

The problem that I am running into is that any of my attempts to run the code as is results in an intermittent behaviour where Chrome and IE9 will usually just return a **ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED** or **Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage** respectively and very occasionally display the expected output "TEST".

I originally tried using a asynchronous approach (Using BeginAcceptTcpClient()) but have reverted back to this simpler technique because I thought this problem might stem from me doing something incorrectly in the asynchronous implementation but it seems that the cause is something else.

Could anyone please provide any guidance?

Comment: Dataavailable being 0 does *not* mean "end of incoming data".

Answer (score 1):

After your first iteration of the loop `while (client.Connected)` you close the connection. Only close it when you are done transferring all data.

Comment: DataAvailable is not reliable (Google for it). It can return false at any time. This is what happened.

Comment: @usr oh, it is "reliable" - it just reliably does something completely unrelated to what most people think it does.

Comment: @MarcGravell this is the best phrasing I have ever heard!

Comment: I have taken a look at how DataAvailable actually works and although accept that while it is not being used correctly in the above example it is adequate because the headers are all received in one go and in no way affects my response to the client.

Answer (score 1):

It's not whether it's synchronous or asynchronous, you're just not responding with a proper HTTP response. Take a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and look at the data being received when you request a regular webpage.

If you return this, it should work:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 4

TEST
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is, I have tried using all the correct http response headers and the behaviour was just as erratic. I never tried with content-length set, so ill try that again and report what happens.

Comment: @MaximGershkovich then please start debugging. What data do you receive, and what data does get sent?